# remote desktop services activex client control IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, remote-desktop, internet-explorer-11, browser-addons

i just installed IE 8.1 and I'm having problem logging into a website that used RD Web Access.  I'm using IE 11

I get an error that says:

:activeX control not enabled. the remote desktop services activex client control is not enabled"

- for testing purposed i have reduced all security settings to medium to allow all activeX
- i do not get a prompt IE information bar to run the activex control
- when i go to manage add ons to try and enable this it's not on the list and i cant add to the list

how do i install and enable this activeX control?

Answer (score 8):

In IE11, F12 to access developer tools.  Scroll down to the bottom, "Emulation" and set the "User Agent String" to Internet Explorer 10.